# Show only dedicated JOB for USER depend on his DESIGNATION using laravel relation

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relation

I have table USERS which has relations with JOBS and DESIGNATIONS and JOBS relations with DESIGNATION. If user logged in he can only see the assigned JOBS based on his designation.
Please see below code.

TABLE STRUCTURES

```
job_user
id | user_id | job_id

designation_user
id | user_id | designation_id

designation_job
id | designation_id | job_id
```

USER MODEL

```
public function designations() {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Designation::class, 'designation_user');
}

public function jobs() {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Job::class, 'job_user');
}
```

JOB MODEL

```
public function designations() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Designation::class, 'job_designation');
}

public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'job_user');
}
```

DESIGNATION MODEL

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'designation_user');
}

public function jobs() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Promo::class, 'job_designation');
}
```

What should be the query for this kind of situation. Thank you for the help.

Comment: can you please share your table structure for better understanding

Comment: can you check something like inside your user model  $this->belongsToMany(jobs::class, designation_job  )

Comment: maybe a scope would be what you are looking for here. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#query-scopes